# makeidx, xstring, forloop and utf8 conflict

Tags: indexing, unicode, loops, xstring

I'm using Danish characters in strings that I split with `\StrCut` from the `×string` package and use within a `\forLoop` from the `forloop` package. The result is not good.

Consider this small example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\StrCut{skøn|skat}{|}\pa\pb

\begin{document}

\pa

\pb

\newcounter{ct}
\forLoop{1}{1}{ct}{
  \index{\pa}
} 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `\StrCut` command splits the string `skøn|skat` into two strings, which it stores in `\pa` and `\pb`.

When I run `latexmk -pdf file.tex` I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3   \item sk\T
                1\o n, 1
```

and the word "sk1øn" is printed in the index instead of "skøn".

If I omit `\StrCut` and use the string `skøn` directly, the problem goes away.

If I omit `\forLoop` and use `\index{\pa}` directly, the problem goes away.

However, I really want to use both.

How can I solve the problem?

(Please don't tell me that the `\forLoop` does nothing useful. I know that. I've reduced this example from a much larger one.)

Comment: You have to announce `\noexpandarg` before using `\StrCut`, see `xstring`'s manual. I can't see the usefulness of a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I said in my question, I've reduced the example from a much larger one. In the full text, the arugment to `\StrCut` has several items separated by `|`. I split them into an array and use a for loop to iterate through the array. In that case the for loop is useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `xstring` fully expands the arguments to its commands; so `ø` is turned into its LaTeX Internal Character Representation and doing `\forLoop` on it doesn't succeed.

See the following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\StrCut{skøn|skat}{|}\pa\pb

\noexpandarg
\StrCut{skøn|skat}{|}\qa\qb

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\pa}

\texttt{\scantokens\expandafter{\meaning\qa}}


\newcounter{ct}
\forLoop{1}{1}{ct}{
  \index{\qa}
}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

that produces this output:

[image]

Note that `\scantokens\expandafter` is just to reinstate the UTF-8 characters, so `ø` is printed; using on the previous `\meaning` wouldn't have any effect.

So, use `\noexpandarg` and live happy.

---

A different solution without `forloop` or `xstring`. Without knowing what you do with those lists, it's a bit difficult to propose a full solution, but this should give an idea.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\managelist}{ O{\use:n} m }
 {
  \ozicz_managelist:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__ozicz_split_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ozicz_managelist:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__ozicz_split_list_seq { | } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ozicz_split_list_seq { #1 { ##1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\printitem}[1]{#1 }

\begin{document}

\managelist{skøn|skat}

\managelist[\printitem]{skøn|skat}

\managelist[\index]{skøn|skat}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

By default `\managelist` just prints the items without spaces between them (this can be changed, of course). If you use the optional argument, each item becomes an argument to the macro in it.

Here's the `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{sk\IeC {\o }n}{1}
\indexentry{skat}{1}
```

The `\IeC {\o }` is normal when an entry is processed before becoming the argument to `\index`.